# Problem with cors and jquery while uploading a file

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a file to an API on a system I'm developing. The front end is using jquery while back-end is using C# (.Net Core).

I have enabled CORS in the backend, and it is all working well. Upload works fine while in localhost, but when I try it on the actual servers, I get this CORS error.

How I send the data:

```
            $('#input-upload').change(function(event) {
                self.form = new FormData();
                self.form.append('arquivo', event.target.files[0]); 

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: ControleDePagamentosModel.getUploadUrl(self.selected), 
                    data: self.form,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST'
                })
                .done(function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.error)
                    {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                    else if (data.message)
                    {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                })
                .fail(function()
                {
                    alert("Erro de comunicação com o servidor de dados!");
                });  
            });
```

The server endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload/{id}/{username}")]
public async Task<ResponseDTO> UploadFGTSAsync([FromForm] IFormFile arquivo, int id, string username)
{
    string path = "";

    if (arquivo !=null && arquivo.Length > 0)
    {
        ...
```

EDIT: My CORS configuration:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRouting();
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("apiPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(
                options => 
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    //options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = 1;
                }
            );
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "EmccampAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
            });

            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddDbContext<DBCONTROLEMPContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ControlEmp")));
            //services.AddDbContext<RMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RM")));

            services.AddTransient<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
}
```

Note that all other requests work.

Comment: What are the cors setting you have enabled ?!

Comment: Try this !
$.ajax(
                {
                    url: ControleDePagamentosModel.getUploadUrl(self.selected), 
                    data: self.form,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST', 
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
      } })

Comment: Didn't work. Note that all other requests work, I have enabled CORS from all origins, methods and headers. I suspect it has something to do with the Content Type, but it gives me a 400 error if I don't use `contentType: false`.

Comment: Hi @ReisAlex, Have you tried the solution that I shared?

Answer (score 0):

> I have enabled CORS in the backend, and it is all working well. Upload works fine while in localhost, but when I try it on the actual servers, I get this CORS error.

> Note that all other requests work.

To troubleshoot the issue, please try to apply your policy to that specific endpoint explicitly, like below.

```
[EnableCors("apiPolicy")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload/{id}/{username}")]
public async Task<ResponseDTO> UploadFGTSAsync([FromForm] IFormFile arquivo, int id, string username)
{
    //...
```

And please check if the browser client make request with a large file while the issue happens. If the request exceed [the `maxAllowedContentLength` limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#configuration), which would cause the issue. You can try to modify and increase the value of `maxAllowedContentLengt`h based on your actual scenario.

```
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="90000000" />
</requestFiltering>
```